# Rload in half wave rectifier

Tags: rectifier

Does Rload play a huge role in a half wave rectifier?, why when I change the value of Rl the output of the half-wave rectifier graph changes?

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit is

- diode rectifier
- filter cap
- Rload

then the size of Rload detemines how fast the capacitor drops in voltage, and that is the ripple voltage.